# need to improve R regex phone number extraction from 26 to 28 different formatting

Tags: r, regex

I am trying to extract from a random text phone numbers in 28 different formats in R. I have read previous posts here on R regex, such as `\` being replaced with `\\`, and running the regex operator with `perl=TRUE`, so I have solved most of my issues. I need help with some debugging.

I use the following regular expression in R:

```
medium_regex2 = "(?:\\+?(\\d{1})?-?\\(?(\\d{3})\\)?[\\s-\\.]?)?(\\d{3})[\\s-\\.]?(\\d{4})[\\s-\\.]?"
```

and run the following code:

```
medium_phone_extract2 <- function(string){
  unlist(regmatches(string,gregexpr(medium_regex2,string, perl=TRUE)))
}
medium_phone_extract2(phonenumbers)
```

The expression spots 26 out of 28 numbers correctly. The 2 missing number formats are: 
"+90-555-4443322"
"+1.517.3002010"

How would you improve the regex so that these 2 formats are also correctly extracted?

edit: the full 28 formats I am trying to extract are:

```
phonenumbers <- c("05554443322",
                  "0555 444 3322",
                  "0555 444 33 22",
                  "5554443322", 
                  "555 444 3322",
                  "555 444 33 22",
                  "905554443322",
                  "+905554443322",
                  "+90-555-4443322",
                  "+1-517-3002010",
                  "+1-(800)-3002010",
                  "+1-517-3002010",
                  "+1.517.3002010",
                  "000-000-0000",
                  "000 000 0000",
                  "000.000.0000",
                  "(000)000-0000",
                  "(000)000 0000",
                  "(000)000.0000",
                  "(000) 000-0000",
                  "(000) 000 0000",
                  "(000) 000.0000",
                  "000-0000",
                  "000 0000",
                  "000.0000",
                  "0000000",
                  "0000000000",
                  "(000)0000000")
howmany_numbers <- length(phonenumbers)
#28
```

And the 26 I am able to extract with the regex are:

```
 [1] "05554443322"      "0555 444 3322"    "5554443322"       "555 444 3322"     "90555444332"     
 [6] "+90555444332"     "0-555-4443322"    "+1-517-3002010"   "+1-(800)-3002010" "+1-517-3002010"  
[11] "517.3002010"      "000-000-0000"     "000 000 0000"     "000.000.0000"     "(000)000-0000"   
[16] "(000)000 0000"    "(000)000.0000"    "(000) 000-0000"   "(000) 000 0000"   "(000) 000.0000"  
[21] "000-0000"         "000 0000"         "000.0000"         "0000000"          "0000000000"      
[26] "(000)0000000"
```

Comment: Please show the other 26 recognised formats for reference.

Comment: there is another big regex for phone extraction , which I am unable to make work in R. 

huge_regex = "\\(?:(?:\\+?1\\s*(?:[.-]\\s*)?)?(?:\\(\\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])\\s*\\)|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\\s*(?:[.-]\\s*)?)?([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\\s*(?:[.-]\\s*)?([0-9]{4})(?:\\s*(?:#|x\\.?|ext\\.?|extension)\\s*(\\d+))?"

Comment: This is a pretty horrendous regex. Anyway, maybe you need to escape the hyphens if you want to match them specifically eg `[\\s\\-\\.]` rather than `[\\s-\\.]`.

Comment: I get my regex expressions after reading many answers here and many blog posts. So the regex I use are among the most comprehensive I could find online. I also enjoy https://regex101.com/ for the explanations, but I still have trouble porting regex101 expression to R. I followed advice in previous posts and replaced \ with \\ and also added perl=TRUE and it made things work. But some fine tuning is needed I guess.

Comment: Sorry, I just meant it is very complicated to understand, not that it was bad.

Comment: I tried your advice gatsky, but escaping the hyphens does not seem to make a difference. The result is same. I think it is something about having a country code with more than 1 digit.

Comment: after (\\d{1})? I added (\\d{2})?, now I can spot 2 digit country codes, but the count still shows 26, so something started to not display.

Comment: I added what you suggested gatsky. this have improved slightly, but still at 26 count.  (\\d{1})?(\\d{2})?(\\d{3})?[\\s\\-\\.]?

Comment: "0555 444 33 22" is not spotted, because the last 4 digits are separated by a space.

Comment: this is my final edited version, it works great now, except when last 4 numbers are formatted as 2 space 2.

medium_regex2 = "(?:\\+?((\\d{1})?|(\\d{2})?|(\\d{3}))?[\\s\\-\\.]?\\(?(\\d{3})\\)?[\\s\\-\\.]?)?(\\d{3})[\\s\\-\\.]?(\\d{4})[\\s\\-\\.]?"

Comment: Yay :-) I added the code for the last 4 digits, now it works and handles last 4 digits and 2 by 2 grouping too. 

medium_regex2 = "(?:\\+?((\\d{1})?|(\\d{2})?|(\\d{3}))?[\\s\\-\\.]?\\(?(\\d{3})\\)?[\\s\\-\\.]?)?(\\d{3})[\\s\\-\\.]?(\\d{4}|\\d{2}\\s\\d{2})[\\s\\-\\.]?"

So now I am able to see all 28 formats. Not bad :-) thanks all. writing here on stackoverflow made me think about the entire thing and work on it.

Comment: You can post  what works as an answer and accept it in two days  if there isn't any other.

Comment: Thank you Nelson, I'll do so, but some tips are arriving yet. I am now much more confident about my regex phone extract code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following regex:

```
(?:\+?\d{0,3}-?\(?[\s.-]?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?)?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{2}\s?\d{2}
```

In case you want to only match it when not inside other digits, you may add `(?<!\d)` / `(?!\d)` lookarounds that prevent a match if there is a digit on the left or right:

```
(?<!\d)(?:\+?\d{0,3}-?\(?[\s.-]?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?)?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{2}\s?\d{2}(?!\d)
```

To ensure the usual word boundary on both sides use

```
(?<!\w)(?:\+?\d{0,3}-?\(?[\s.-]?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?)?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{2}\s?\d{2}\b
```

In R, do not forget to double all backslashes in the string literal:

```
regex <- "(?<!\\w)(?:\\+?\\d{0,3}-?\\(?[\\s.-]?\\d{3}\\)?[\\s.-]?)?\\d{3}[\\s.-]?\\d{2}\\s?\\d{2}\\b"
```

**Main points**:

- `((\\d{1})?|(\\d{2})?|(\\d{3}))?` is better written as `\d{0,3}`, zero to three digits pattern (alternation makes matching process more resource consuming compared to a more linear, straight-forward pattern)
- `[\\s.-]` is preferred to `[\\s\\-\\.]` since a hyphen is better placed at the end of the character class (no need to escape it there) and note that `.` always matches a literal `.` inside a character class
- `(\\d{4}|\\d{2}\\s\\d{2})` can and should be re-written as `\\d{2}\\s?\\d{2}` matching 2 digits followed with an optional whitespace and then 2 digits.
- Not sure you really want to match a whitespace, hyphen or dot at the end of the pattern, so I suggest removing `[\\s-\\.]?` at the end.

Comment: really great tips, thank you so much! Great critic of the code!